# Device Id and Provisioning Profile

Tags: iphone, provisioning-profile

Is it possible to test an app which has apples push notification service enabled (APNS) on simulator? If so, where can I get the device id (UUID, it should be 40 hex characters) so that I can create a provisioning profile?

In short, I am unable to create a provisioning profile since I am unable to get the device id which is 40 hex characters. Currently I have this uuid D1648548-6C35-511B-B0D0-258808BD2026, which is only 36 including 4 hyphens.

Answer (score 2):

On simulator the push notification doesn't work. You need a device.
Coming to provisioning profile, device id and device token both are 2 different hex characters. If you connect the device with the mac you can get the device id from xcode in organizer tab. This is device id which need to be added to the provisioning profile.

When you implement push notification and run that app on device you get the device token which is used as a communication with APNs and device.

Hope this help.

Answer (score 1):

push notification service is not enabled by apple on simulator. u need to use a device. see apple guide about push notifcation. you will be told in detail about it

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html